# How do you configure Xcode Server (Bot) to only keep the n most recent integrations?

Tags: xcode7, xcode-server

We've recently discovered that Xcode Server (i.e. a Bot) will keep *all* past integrations. (We discovered this as the builds started failing and we realized the CI server was completely out of disk space).

How can you configure a bot (or the server in general) to only keep the last `n` integrations? Or even the last `n` days?

If there is no built-in setting, is there a way to accomplish this via a `cron` job that *doesn't* have to use the [unofficial XCode Server API](https://github.com/czechboy0/XcodeServer-API-Docs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current max disk size is a ratio of 0.75 of the capacity (if I understand the output well). You can see it for yourself if you run `curl -k -u USER:PASS https://localhost:20343/api/settings`. You might be able to change it by calling this API as a `PATCH` request with a modified value for `max_percent_disk_usage` to something smaller and then giving it time to clean up. I haven't tested that however.

If you're interested in how this works, see `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/xcs/xcsd/routes/routes_setting.js` line 19. From there you should be able to dig deeper and see for yourself.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This was very helpful, @czechboy!

The JSON document returned when you fetch the settings will contain the `_id` of the xcode instance whose settings you wish to modify, and you must send the `PATCH` request to `https://localhost:20343/api/settings/<id>`. The body of the request should be something like:

```
{ "set_props": { "max_percent_disk_usage": 0.40 } }
```

After doing this I needed to restart the server before old files were cleaned up.

Comment: This is an old issue but here goes, when I try to call patch I get a 403 "Could not login because a valid client certificate is required and was not provided" Any ideas?